# webdriver mouse hover in Chrome stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver

I had this hover function, which was working perfectly fine, in Chrome but stopped working on 14 July 2013. I guess it has something to do with the browser update. Please suggest what should I do to resolve this problem. This is the following code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement Mainmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/a"));
WebElement Submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/ul/li[1]/a"));
WebElement Childsubmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
actions.moveToElement(Mainmenu).moveToElement(Submenu).moveToElement(Childsubmenu).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Could you please provide a few more details as to how its no longer working? Do you see any of the menus opening? Are you receiving exceptions or errors?

Comment: the hover and click on menu does not work and no links are clicked. and throws an error saying element not click able

Comment: Is the exception tail `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)` where x and y are coords of the `element`?

Comment: Thanks Mark but it just started workin without any changes and with the same chrome version. Couldn't figure out what  caused it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in Chrome, Element Click on menus and sub-menus only works if your mouse pointer is not over the browser on which code is running. Place the pointer to else where away from the browser or if feasible use another screen while running your code. Works for me!